# saltstack complaining about "invalid returner"

Tags: salt-stack

I've got a couple of returners configured using the schedule state.

One works fine, the other logs an error:

```
Job state.sls using invalid returner: <name of returner>. Ignoring
```

I have found no documentation on what this means; reading the salt code doesn't enlighten me.

Can someone point me in the right direction about what this means?

Comment: what is the name of the returner that gives an error ? it seems you have a wrong name

Comment: The name of the returner specified in `_schedule.conf` matches the name of the filename (+.py) in the returners directory.

Comment: can you mention the returner name or is it classified ?

Comment: It's `panw_rawfile_json`

Comment: it seems that you are using a custom returner, are you sure that you have loaded it correctly ? can you try to sync it to other minions ? check the following: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/returners/#using-custom-returner-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been caused by a syntax error in the returner. I just wish the salt error messages were a bit more useful.